# Add a timestamp to a moved row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the function I am using to move a row when I press a check box, it works fine, I just want to add next to the moved row a timestamp, to register the time when that was made, but I can't do it.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Editor's note to suggestion author: please do not change brace styles when editing. It is a code style preference, strive to preserve it. Allman style is also a rare choice for JS brace style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Instead of moving the row to the other sheet, you get the row data, add a timestamp to the row data as a new column, and then append this data as a new row to the other sheet.

```
if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
  var row = r.getRow(),
      numColumns = s.getLastColumn(),
      targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed"),
      rowData = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
  rowData.push(new Date());
  targetSheet.appendRow(rowData);
  s.deleteRow(row);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush;
}
```